# Is Biff Either an Applicative?

Tags: haskell

The `bifunctors` library exposes the following data type:

```
newtype Biff p f g a b = Biff { runBiff :: p (f a) (g b) }
```

As witnessed in the library, `Biff p f g a` is a `Functor` if `p` is a `Bifunctor` and `g` is a `Functor`.

```
instance (Bifunctor p, Functor g) => Functor (Biff p f g a) where
  fmap f = Biff . second (fmap f) . runBiff
  {-# INLINE fmap #-}
```

I suspect (but have not proved) that it is additionally the case that `Biff Either f g a` is an applicative functor if:

- `f` is an `Alternative` functor
- `g` is an `Applicative` functor

Here is the relevant type tetris:

```
instance (Alternative f, Applicative g) => Applicative (Biff Either f g a)
  where
  pure a = Biff $ Right $ pure a
  Biff f <*> Biff v = Biff $ go f v
    where
    go (Left  x) (Right _) = Left x
    go (Right _) (Left  x) = Left x
    go (Left  x) (Left  y) = Left $ x <|> y
    go (Right x) (Right y) = Right $ x <*> y
```

Is this a valid applicative instance?

Comment: Nothing jumps out at me immediately that would cause it to fall. Shouldn't be too hard to prove the laws for a simple instance like this (possibly somewhat tedious). Have you tried a typeclass laws proof before?

Comment: I have for other stuff, although I'm not particularly skilled at it. The reason I just dumped it here is because I just finished packing up 50% of my apartment and am feeling very intellectually lazy :)

Comment: Case expanding `Biff f <*> Biff v` suggests to me that at least the applicative identity laws always work, since for `let x = Biff $ Right $ (); zip x y ~ zip y x ~ y`. The associativity is always the big problem...

Comment: It looks like you do not really need `Alternative f`, but only `Semigroup (f a)` (?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Said another way, `Biff Either f g a` is the composition of two applicative functors `Either (f a)` and `g`, which is therefore an applicative functor.

Comment: So actually I don't even need the `Alternative` instance, the implicit `Const` semigroup should suffice for combining `Left`s (as @chi alluded to).